# WebLogic Server Shared Javascript Libraries

Tags: javascript, java, weblogic, war

Where can I put in the **weblogic server structure folders** some javascript libraries so that they can be used in all my projects?

**UPDATE**: I put the javascript libraries that I had now in a .war file and I am  using them from there but is this a good practice?

```
js-libraries.war                   
|- APP-INF   
|- META-INF   
|- JS   
   |- folder-libraries-js   
      |- js code....   
      |- js code....   
      |- js code....
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a good solution to use a shared library to share resources like javascript code between several web applications.  You can also put these static files in a front end host like Apache to improve your performance and share them.